# What is the difference between "a female" and " the female" in this paragraph?

Tags: meaning-in-context, articles

I have read a book talking about monogamous relationship. The book has a paragraph:

> Nevertheless, few men like sharing their women, and many do not mind having one woman at a time if she happens to be great — not only drop-dead gorgeous, but also lovely to talk to and spend time with, both in and outside the bedroom. But most males are in long-term monogamous relationships because they have managed merely to find *a* female, not because they have found *the* female.

In the book, the writer said that monogamous relationship is not natural, and many men are in long-term monogamous relationships because they find it to to be a way to make their female stay and be faithful. But I don't understand the difference between "a female" and " the female" in this paragraph. Can anyone help me?

Comment: Well the basic difference is the use of the two articles: "a" implies 'one of many' while "the" specifies exactly about which female they're talking.

Comment: After reading your text two things came to my mind. 1) a female; the man is such a miserable, desperate creature that by finding a random female, we feel much relief. We didn't find "the one" "the special" "the perfect one" but we managed to find a -random- female "nonetheless". So that is a relief. 
2) stop reading that book.

Comment: (1) *If I see a person, I wave at **a** person*. I could be waving at a third party. (2) *If I see a person, I wave at **the** person*. This makes clear that I wave at the person that I see.

Answer (score 2):

It's denoting the emotional importance of the woman in question.

**A** female - is anyone.  A guy has gone out and found a woman, any woman.  There is little emotional importance here and not much in the way of deciding factors.

**The** female - has emotional importance.  This is the "soul mate" and has a strong emotional bond.

Most men I know have a monogamous relationship with their "**the** female", and not just the first one they meet (as implied in your quoted text).